# Octave's equivalent to Matlab's which('filename', '-all')

Tags: matlab, path, octave

In Matlab, `which('filename', '-all')` returns all the files with the given `'filename'` in the Matlab path, but Octave only returns the first one (not the shadowed ones). Is there an easy way get the equivalent in Octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a longstanding feature request for Octave that as of this post has not yet been resolved. See [Bug #32973](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?32973) and [Bug #32088](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?32088).  The latter link appears to have a workaround patch and function attached that never quite made it into the main codebase.

UPDATE 16 Nov 22: while the bug has not been fixed, rather than silently fail Octave v8 will now provide a warning to the user that the option is not yet implemented and only the first result will be returned.